# spring controller convention to use

Tags: spring-mvc

There are 2 formats for writing controller handlers in spring.
Could someone help summarizing what determines the format to be used.
Also whats the format of preference?
Being a new-bie,this would help being on teh right track.

Option 1:

```
@RequestMapping(value=".....", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String loadFormPage(Model m) {
        m.addAttribute("subscriber", new Subscriber());
        return "formPage";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="....", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String submitForm(@ModelAttribute Subscriber subscriber, Model m) {
        m.addAttribute("message", "Successfully saved person: " + subscriber.toString());
        return "formPage";
    }
```

Option 2:

```
@RequestMapping(value=".....")
    public ModelAndView personPage() {
        return new ModelAndView("person-page", "person-entity", new Person());
    }

    @RequestMapping(value=".....")
    public ModelAndView processPerson(@ModelAttribute Person person) {
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
        modelAndView.setViewName("person-result-page");

        modelAndView.addObject("pers", person);

        return modelAndView;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A controller method in Spring can support zero-to-many input parameters, and the principal mechanisms in Spring for specifying input parameters are the `@RequestParam` and the `@ModelAttribute` annotations.
The `@RequestParam` annotation  is used to bind individual request parameters, like string and integers, to method parameters in the controller.
The `@ModelAttribute` annotation is used to bind complex objects, like domain objects, data transfer objects and/or form backing objects, to method parameters in a controller.

The annotaton is determined by the variable type.
primitive variables will be annotated with `@RequestParam`
complex variables will be annotated with `@ModelAttribute`

The annotation name is derived from the variable name

A controller method in Spring can also output model data, and the principal mechanism in Spring for specifying output model data is the `ModelAndView` object.
In the event that there isn't any data to be returned by the method, the controller method can simply return a `String` that represents the view that should be rendered.
If the controller method does return data, then a `ModalAndView` object needs to be instantiated and each output variable is added as a model attribute to the `ModelAndView` object.